# In XMPP MUC is it possible to publish geolocation information?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, xmpp, openfire

In XMPP [MUC](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html) is it possible to publish geolocation information of each online user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, the clients can simply include a `<geoloc>` element (defined in [XEP-0080](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0080.html)) in their presence to the room:

```
<presence to="room@roomserver/nickname">
    <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
    <geoloc xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/geoloc'>
      <accuracy>20</accuracy>
      <country>Italy</country>
      <lat>45.44</lat>
      <locality>Venice</locality>
      <lon>12.33</lon>
    </geoloc>
</presence>
```

Subsequent updates would leave out the `<x>` element naturally, as these are only included when joining a room.